# Should back end processes be included in use cases in requirements document?

Tags: requirements

We're writing a requirements document for our client and need to include the use cases of the system. We're following [this template](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ajQxre-NOEM0J%3awww.jaysonjc.com/dl/srs/J2Lite%2520SRS%2520Template.odt%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk):

```
ID
Description
Actors
Precondition
Basic Steps
Alternate Steps
Exceptions
Business validations/Rules
Postconditions
```

In the Basic Steps section, should we include steps that the system performs in the back end or should we only include steps that the user directly interacts with?

Example:

Basic Steps for Search 1:

```
User goes to search page
User enters term
User presses search
System matches search term with database entries
System displays results
```

vs

Basic Steps for Search 2:

```
User goes to search page
User enters term
User presses search
System displays results
```

Comment: Advice: Don't rely on Use Cases alone to capture all your requirements and business rules.

Answer (score 1):

"steps that the user directly interacts with" is the definition of a use case.

Things the backend may (or may not do) are an appendix to the use case.  They're not testable, and they're not interactions.

A Use Case is defined pretty strictly to focus on testable behavior that's observable by **one** actor.

"description of steps or actions between a user (or "actor") and a software system which leads the user towards something useful"

If there's no interaction with the central actor, that means it's not part of the use case.

An appendix or supplement can be provided in case the algorithm is (a) important and (b) required and (c) known in advance.  This is rare, but can happen.

When there are complex interactions "behind the scenes", those are **separate** use cases with a **separate** collection of "behind the scenes" actors.  Other systems, generally, are other actors.

A user -- a person -- doesn't see or interact with the other systems.  They don't really exist.  The primary system could be providing results by magic.  Or they could be "canned" or static or computed in advance.

Another system -- also an actor -- doesn't see or interact with the user.  The primary system sends random requests for random reasons.

Comment: I am going to have to disagree with you on this one. A use case is always from the perspective of an "actor". An actor could be an "end user" or could very well be another "system" as well. And all backend processes do need to be captured in terms of the functionality that they serve, IMHO

Comment: @InSane: When the actor is a separate system, that's a separate use case written for a separate (non-human) actor.  What's important is that a use case is from the point of view of **one** actor.  A second use case from the view of a second actor is a way to handle this.

Comment: hmm interesting. that's exactly what we were debating...

Comment: @bizso09: "that's exactly what we were debating"?  Really?  Can you clarify the question, then.  The answer I provided seems pretty clear.  If it doesn't provide a resolution to the debate, but just continues the debate, then please provide some clue as to what about the answer is ambiguous or unclear.  Obviously, I've failed to provide a clear path forward.  However.  I can't see what's missing.  Please provide some sense of what's ambiguous our unclear in the answer.

Comment: you're answer is clear. What I was referring to was what @InSane wrote. Could there be multiple actors in a use case?

Comment: @bizso09: "Could there be multiple actors in a use case". No.  I guess the answer wasn't clear enough, then.

Answer (score 0):

A use case document should describe the actions taken by the user, and the resulting actions taken by the system. Each step should have a user action and the system response, so a single step would look something like this.

> user clicks search button
>
> system will display results of search, results will be paginated if over ten, results will include title and price